# provide default value in clojure.spec

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

Is there a way to specify default values for keys mentioned in `(s/keys :opt [::k1 ::k2])`?

Something like:

```
(s/keys :opt [(with-default ::k1 "default1") (with-default ::k2 "default2")])
```

Or it is more idiomatic to handle default values outside of clojure.spec?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so, as `clojure.spec` is mainly concerned with data validation and structure, not with enriching, coercing or changing data. So you would have to do it yourself. E.g.:

```
(merge {::k1 "default" ::k2 "default"} {::k1 2}) ;;=> {::k1 2, ::k2 "default"}
```

or using associative destructuring:

```
(let [{k1 ::k1 k2 ::k2 :or {k1 "default", k2 "default"}} 
      {::k1 2}] 
  [k1 k2]) ;; => [2 "default"]
```

or similarly:

```
(let [{:keys [::k1 ::k2] :or {k1 "default" k2 "default"}} 
      {::k1 2}] 
  [k1 k2]) ;; => [2 "default"]
```

Comment: I would agree, but the documentation says that clojure.spec/conform may modify it's input. For examle when :into parameter is given to clojure.spec/coll-of

Answer (score 2):

There is no explicit feature for this in spec and I would expect you to handle it in the code, not in the spec.

It is possible to build something that does this with `s/conformer`, but I would not consider that a recommended use of that feature.